# How do I get the number of Views on a Tweet?

Tags: javascript, twitter, fetch-api

Now that Twitter has [View counts](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/view-counts) on its Tweets, I was wondering how to get this information given a specific Tweet ID.

I have the following code which works to get the number of likes a Tweet has using the Twitter API:

```
const BEARER_TOKEN = 'BEARER_TOKEN';

// Returns the number of likes on the Tweet with the given tweetID.
async function getTweetLikes(tweetID) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/${tweetID}.json`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  );

  const tweet = await response.json();
  return tweet.favorite_count;
}

// Get the Tweet ID of the current page
const tweetID = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3];
console.log('tweetID', tweetID);

getTweetLikes(tweetID).then((likes) => {
  console.log(`Tweet ${tweetID} has ${likes} likes.`);
});
```

But ideally, I'd like to modify this to get both the number of likes *and* views. Something like this:

```
const tweet = await response.json();
return [tweet.favorite_count, tweet.view_count];

...

getTweetLikesAndViews(tweetID).then((result) => {
  console.log(`Tweet ${tweetID} has ${result[0]} likes and ${result[1]} views.`);
});
```

Unfortunately, there is no `view_count` field that is returned. And I can't find anything about it on the Twitter API reference either, so I would appreciate it if anyone has a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets-id) can get the API liked count and viewed counts.

```
GET /2/tweets/:id/?tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=public_metrics

GET https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/{tweet-id}/?tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=public_metrics
```

Example : Tweet ID = 1582388225049780230's get liked counts and viewed counts

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/1582388225049780230/?tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=public_metrics
```

Result

```
$ node get-metrix.js
{
    "data": {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "7_1582388001845678082"
            ]
        },
        "text": "Can the King overcome the clock in an epic battle against Father Time?\n\nWatch @kingjames vs. Father Time in con
tests of strength, stamina, wit, and… karaoke?! #LeBronXX   https://????",
        "public_metrics": {
            "retweet_count": 912,
            "reply_count": 783,
            "like_count": 6261,
            "quote_count": 191
        },
        "id": "1582388225049780230",
        "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
            "1582388225049780230"
        ]
    },
    "includes": {
        "media": [
            {
                "media_key": "7_1582388001845678082",
                "public_metrics": {
                    "view_count": 782529
                },
                "type": "video"
            }
        ]
    }
}
viewed : 782529
liked : 6261
```

It matched it's tweet's liked number (red box)
Viewed video (blue box)

[image: ![enter image description here]

Full code

```
const axios = require('axios')
const config = require('./config.json');

const getAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
            '',
            {
                params: {
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: config.API_KEY,
                    password: config.API_KEY_SECRET
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.access_token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};

const getTweetTextMetrics = async (token, tweet_id) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(
            `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/${tweet_id}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token,
                },
                params: {
                    'tweet.fields': 'public_metrics',
                    'expansions': 'attachments.media_keys',
                    'media.fields': 'public_metrics'
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};

getAccessToken()
    .then((token) => {
        getTweetTextMetrics(token, '1582388225049780230')
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
                console.log('viewed : ' + result.includes.media[0].public_metrics.view_count);
                console.log('liked : ' + result.data.public_metrics.like_count);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
```

Configuration in `config.json` file.

```
{
    "API_KEY" : "7hK ... your API key here ... GND",
    "API_KEY_SECRET" : "Zr4... your API key secret here ... qX0",
}
```

Result in terminal
[image]

How to find the count from documentation?
It is not easy, hard to find but it is there.

You can follow red box for finding it.
That applied my demo code.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets-id

Same Idea how to find viewed count.

[image]

---

Update
For checking non video tweet

```
https://twitter.com/Nike/status/1586148884463525889
```

[image]

Result

```
$ node get-metrix.js
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1586148884463525889",
        "text": "Pregnancy is the ultimate endurance event. How can fitness fit
in?\n\nLaurel Proulx, pelvic health PT, gives us an expert guide to navigating p
re- and postnatal exercise on the latest episode of the Nike Trained podcast. \n
\nListen below� \nhttps://x.xx/xxxxxxx",
        "public_metrics": {
            "retweet_count": 25,
            "reply_count": 73,
            "like_count": 198,
            "quote_count": 0,
            "impression_count": 0
        },
        "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
            "1586148884463525889"
        ]
    }
}
{}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this only work for video tweets or does it also work for all tweets?

Comment: @yayabosh, I updated my answer, non video tweet also support for metrics counts

Comment: In your update, you only show the number of likes on the Tweet, but not the number of Views. The number of Views on a Tweet is a new feature that's different from the `like_count`. Try looking at a recent Tweet that doesn't contain a video (the Tweet in your example is from October, before this feature was released) to see the View count. Currently, I don't think the API supports returning this value.

Comment: In the upper tweet, there are no views number, it shows only `retweets` and `likes` In Tweet status. API only support UI shows items.

Comment: Right, but if you find a recent Tweet, like on [this Tweet from today](https://twitter.com/espn/status/1612933913621454850), you can see the number of Views on the Tweet itself. The Tweet you linked was from October, which is prior to the Views feature being released.

Comment: That is non public information for `Number of times the Tweet has been viewed.` You needs to pay account. You can see at `non_public_metrics.impression_count`  in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets-id)

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like `public_metrics.impression_count` works. I tested it using the API you linked.

Comment: I am happy to hear, you got information via `public_metrics `