# twitter IDs, data analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I need help for a project on my uni. I have to reproduce a scientific paper which makes a sentiment analysis using twitter data. My prof has given me the data, but the dataset is in .txt format and they are only tweet IDs. How can I work with them? I created a twitter Api, I just don't know what to do with only twitter IDs with my analysis. is there a way where I can extract whole twitter text from id, to do the cleaning of data and classification?

I opened twitter Api

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/JoseIVP/f9b964eb9442cd0e0955249ea6395014) is probably a good starting point. Use `tweepy` get the latest tweets of said Twitter IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Using ['tweepy'](https://www.tweepy.org/) with `get_tweets()` API.

It will return tweet text by [Tweet ID](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweet-lookup)

`ids` is list of tweet id, Up to 100 ids for single request.
If you more then 100, you needs to make a group. each group 100 ids.

[image]

#### Demo code (suppose less then 100 ids)

```
import tweepy

bearer_token ="your token"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

tweets_file = open("tweet_ids.txt", "r")
data = tweets_file.read()
tweet_ids = data.split("\n")
tweets_file.close()

tweets = client.get_tweets(ids=tweet_ids)

for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.id, " -> ",tweet.text)
    print('---------------------------------------------------------')
```

#### With text file, the `tweet_ids.txt` file name.

```
1615009611186069504
1591179284991070208
1590380720853114881
```

#### result

```
>python get-tweets.py
1615009611186069504  ->  Municipio: Santo Antônio Da Platina - PR
Setor censitário: 412410305000028
População: 718
Área (Km2): 1.31
Densidade (hab/Km2): 548.06
Zona: urbana
 https://xxx/KagyCLHLrM https://xxx/z1YDyTJArx
---------------------------------------------------------
1591179284991070208  ->  At a secret lab, a debate erupts…bias comes into play when discussing Mbappe and 2006 Ronaldinho. A multiverse will settle the score, but the discussion isn’t complete until Cristiano Ronaldo is finally pulled in. Watch the teaser ahead of the full film launch on Nov 16. #NikeFC https://xxx/iDlGF9Kkak
---------------------------------------------------------
1590380720853114881  ->  Welcome to Nike FC. We’re not a club. We’re a community. If you love the game of football, you’re a part of Nike FC. Let’s change the game, create the culture, and build the future together. #nikefc https://xxx/8LzSQptDc0
---------------------------------------------------------
```

You can more tweet data with this threads

[Getting the Account of users who liked or retweeted a Tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75042233/tweepy-getting-the-accounts-of-users-who-liked-or-retweeted-a-tweet/75045235#75045235)

[Get all of re tweeter user list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75042233/tweepy-getting-the-accounts-of-users-who-liked-or-retweeted-a-tweet/75045235#75045235)

[Get the number of Views on a Tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74905217/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-views-on-a-tweet/74905466#74905466)